# Is it possible to decrypt an RSA ciphertext with only $N$ and $e$?

Tags: rsa

Is it possible to perform RSA decryption if one only knows $N$ and $e$?

Failing that, what is the maximum key length where brute-force is still practically feasible?

Comment: The $N$ you provide is 512-bit long, not 128 (unless I messed up a calculation). If it were 128 bits long, and you had a couple of hours (possibly days depending on your gear) to spare, brute-forcing it would be feasible. For 512 I'm not so sure.

Comment: I've edited your question. If my edit gets accepted you'll notice it's been trimmed down quite a bit. I did this because requests to decrypt a block of data are off-topic on this site, and your question would get closed as a result. If you feel I've been too liberal with my edit, feel free to rollback, but keep in mind the above. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

The current best way of decryption an RSA ciphertext (assuming good padding was used) is to factor $N$ into its prime factors $p$ and $q$, and from that, reconstruct the decryption exponent $d = e^{-1} \bmod lcm( p-1, q-1 )$

The current record for factoring an RSA-type modulus (with large prime factors, and not of a special form) is 768 bits.

It is likely that, in the next couple years, slightly larger modulii will be factored; the record for "largest general number factored" has been slowly increasing; someone might manage to factor a 1024 bit number within the next decade.  There is little reason to expect that RSA modulii significantly larger  will be vulnerable to factoring in the near future.

Comment: what does lcm  stands for ?

Comment: @user10500: lcm == "Least Common Multiple"; lcm(a,b) is the smallest integer that is a multiple of both a and b.  We also have $lcm(a,b) = ab / gcd(a,b)$ (where gcd is the more commonly known greatest common divisor function)